# Mostrar json en html

Tags: javascript

Tengo este codigo el cual me devuelve un html

```
const convertToData = (data,select) => {

    params = {
        selectData: data,
        select: select,
    };

    getConvertedData(params).then(response => {
        data = response;

    }).catch(error => {
        if (error.code == 500){
            return console.log(error.message);
        }
        console.log(error);
    });

    return data;
}
```

asi : `"<h5><span class=\"badge badge-primary\">D\u00eda de llamada Martes<\/span><\/h5><h5><span class=\"badge badge-primary\">D\u00eda de llamada Jueves<\/span><\/h5>"`

Al mostrarlo por consola me funciona, pero cuando quiero retornalo a este codigo:

```
${zone_id ? convertToData(zone_id.callDays,"callDays") : ''}
```

me aparece `undefined`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getConvertedData` es función *asincrónica*, que significa que no puede devolver un resultado "immediamente". Funciónes asincrónicos exigen `.then` or `.catch` para utilizarlas: ellos "piensan" durante algún tiempo y pasan un resultado a functión de `then` or un error a función de `catch`, mientras el codigo abajo de llama de `getConvertedData` continúa siendo ejecutado. Cuando se ejecuta `return data`, `data` aún no está llegado.

Solución es estudiar como trabajar con funciónes asincrónicos https://www.adictosaltrabajo.com/2017/02/09/asyncawait-en-javascript/ Es conocimiento muy importante de javascript moderno. Suerte!